# Is every finite group a subgroup of this type of generalization of almost simple groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

Recall, a group $G$ is an almost simple group if there is an non-abelian simple group $S$ such that $S \leq G \leq \operatorname{Aut}(S)$

We will define a $k$-almost simple as follows.

When $0$--almost simple is a non-abelian simple group.

For $k \geq 1$, a group $G$ is $k$-almost simple if there exists a group $S$ such that S is $k-1$ almost simple and $S \leq G \leq \operatorname{Aut}(S)$.

Notice that under this definition, $1$-almost simple groups are just the almost simple groups.

**Question:** For any finite group $G$, does there exist a $k>0$ such that $G$ is contained in some finite $k$-almost simple group?

Comment: Isn't every finite group a subgroup of some alternating $A_n?$ Are simple groups not almost-simple?

Comment: I think you should read the [Schreier conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreier_conjecture) more carefully: you seem to be confusing the automorphism group $\text{Aut}(S)$ with the outer automorphism group $\text{Out}(S)$. The statement *the automorphism group of any finite simple group is solvable* is wrong: if $S$ is a non-cyclic finite simple group then the natural embedding $S \hookrightarrow \text{Aut}(S)$ is an injection, so if $\text{Aut}(S)$ were solvable then $S$ would be solvable, which contradicts the existence of non-cyclic, non-solvable, finite simple groups.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: You have the containment backwards. You would want $A_n\leq G\leq\mathrm{Aut}(A_n)$.

Comment: Well, you've used $G$ in two different ways. First in a definition of $k$-simple, and then as a general group $G.$ The general group $G$ is contained in a simple group, and a simple group is $1$-almost simple.

Comment: @Lee, good point. That is also an obvious reason I should have realized my statement was incorrect. Removed part about Schreier because it is obviously wrong.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you. That does show the answer to my question is trivially yes since $A_n$ is always simple for $n \geq 5$. If you put that as a separate answer I will accept it.

Comment: In fact it is not too hard to prove that, for a finite nonabelian simple group $S$, we have ${\rm Aut}({\rm Aut}(S)) = {\rm Aut}(S)$, so the $k$-almost simple groups for $k \ge 1$ are just the almost simple groups.